# Is it good practice in Java to implement the clone method using serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, clone

I saw several tutorials online where serialization and subsequent deserialization is used to implement deep cloning in Java.
My feeling is, that this is a solution that is fast to implement and therefore widespread but might have caveats that I currently don't see.

Is that way of implementing `clone()` good style? Isn't it slow? Should deep cloning really be done that way? What better ways exist?

Comment: `clone()` in Java is generally considered a mistake (do the google search on this topic), however it still exists for backwards compatibility. You shouldn't use `clone()`, implement your own copy constructor instead.

Comment: In my opinion if you need deep cloning it is an indication of the following problems: your domain is mutable, your domain is too complex (because you cannot implement copy constructors) and most importantly you do not control your code - you do not know where a domain object might be changed and how - that is the reason you need a deep clone, right?

Comment: Regarding this method: both slow (converting everything to string format through the convoluted Java serialization), and memory-consuming (in addition to the two objects and their sub-objects, you have the giant string object.

Comment: I would think it is a bad practice, but then where I saw it used: in an object hierarchy with Jackson and Hibernate annotations and it was used to circumvent the session of the Hibernate entity manager, so when calling save after cloning you would create a new record in the database.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak: Let's view `clone()` as a concept here and see it as the same as the copy constructor. I don't want to discuss the difference between the two but discuss whether a copy constructor implemented via serialization is good or bad.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice in Java to implement the clone method using
>   serialization?

If you use serialization to clone an object you have to necessarily unserialize the serialized object to create the cloned object. It makes two operations where the second seems be an overhead as it should not be performed if you implement the cloning operation at the hand or with a mapper API (ex: SpringBean, Common apache, ModelMapper, Dozzer...).
So it has without no doubt an impact on the performance. If you do this processing very occasionally, I don't think that it should be a problem (even if it seems to be a useless overhead and you have alternative ways) but if you use it often I think that it may have a cost.

Besides, why implementing `Clonable` to clone an object by using serialization instead of forgetting `Cloneable` that is a clumsy API and  using directly  the `deserialization` mechanism ?

Comment: The question is more about whether these unrelated processes - serialization and cloning - should be thrown together just because a deserialized object happens to be a clones object. That seams to be a lot of overhead ...

Comment: No it should not. Cloning is only a side effect of serializing. And as explained and you understand, it adds an useless overhead.